# R converting to long format, pattern

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to convert a data.table like this one from wide format to long.

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(   
  ID = c(1:5, NA),
  Name = c("Bob","Ana","Smith","Sam","Big","Lulu"),
  Kind_2001 = factor(sample(c(letters[1:3], NA), 6, TRUE)),
  Kind_2002 = factor(sample(c(letters[1:3], NA), 6, TRUE)),
  Kind_2003 = factor(sample(c(letters[1:3], NA), 6, TRUE)),
  Conc_2001 = sample(99,6),
  Conc_2002 = sample(79,6),
  Conc_2003 = sample(49,6)
  )


ID  Name Kind_2001 Kind_2002 Kind_2003 Conc_2001 Conc_2002 Conc_2003
1   Bob         b        NA         c        38        22        24
2   Ana         b         c         b        77        31        29
3 Smith         c         c        NA        91         2        49
4   Sam        NA         a         b        21        30         9
5   Big         a         a         c        62        66        38
NA  Lulu       NA         a        NA        12        26        30
```

And I would like to get something like this:

```
ID   Name   Year    Kind   Conc    
1    Bob    2001    b      38
1    Bob    2002    NA     22
1    Bob    2003    c      24
2    Ana    2001    b      77
2    Ana    2002    c      31
2    Ana    2003    b      29
...
```

The real table has many more variables, I'm looking for a solution without explicitly saying every column name or number, detecting automatically the pattern.
I have two kind of columns, some ending with an underscore and a four digit year, such as _2001, and the other without that ending.
Some can have an underscore in the middle of the name (this will be kept untransformed).
I would like to transform the columns ending with a year to long format.

I've tried with

```
melt(DT, id=1:2, variable.name = "year")
or with 
melt(DT, id=1:2, measure=patterns("_2[0-9][0-9][0-9]$"))
```

but I'm not getting what I want.

Maybe I first need to filter the names with gsub.

PD: I've found this solution.

```
posi <- grep("_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$",colnames(DT))
work <- unique(gsub("_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$","",colnames(DT)[posi]))
melt(DT, measure=patterns(paste0("^",work)), variable="year", value.name=work)
```

It almost works but the year column is not populated properly. I'm missing something or it's a bug.
And I'm sure it could be written simpler.

```
ID  Name year Kind Conc
 1   Bob    1    b   38
 2   Ana    1    b   77
 3 Smith    1    c   91
 4   Sam    1   NA   21
 5   Big    1    a   62
NA  Lulu    1   NA   12
 1   Bob    2   NA   22
 2   Ana    2    c   31
 3 Smith    2    c    2
 4   Sam    2    a   30
 5   Big    2    a   66
NA  Lulu    2    a   26
 1   Bob    3    c   24
 2   Ana    3    b   29
 3 Smith    3   NA   49
 4   Sam    3    b    9
 5   Big    3    c   38
NA  Lulu    3   NA   30
```

Regards

I've tried eddi solution with my database and I get the error:

"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 756.5 Mb"
even though I have 16GB of memory.

Comment: If you want two value columns ("Kind" and "Conc") you have to supply two patterns -- for example `melt(DT, id = 1:2, measure.vars = patterns("^Kind", "^Conc"), value.name = c("Kind", "Conc"), variable.name = "Year")`

Comment: But I don't have just Kind and Conc, I have approximately 500 variables. I would like to do it without telling explicitly every one.

Comment: @skan you can populate your `measure.vars` then, ever heard of `as.call(c(as.name("patterns"), your_500_vars))` ?

Comment: @mtoto wrote a working, simple and elegant code, but I would prefer to do it with data.table.  Could you write an answer too?

Comment: Maybe @arun could help

Comment: In order to be able to perform this operation in a very big dataset I've set the system pagefilesize to 250GB (a whole SSD disk), but it seems that it's not used. When I see the task manager it seems that only the physical memory is being used (16GB), at least in the computer at the university (Windows 7).

Comment: Anybody think it could be easy to do it with sqlite instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option that's more robust with respect to the order of your columns, as well as missing/extra years:

```
dcast(melt(DT, id.vars = c("ID", "Name"))
        [, .(ID, Name, sub('_.*', '', variable), sub('.*_', '', variable), value)],
      ID + Name + V4 ~ V3)
#    ID  Name   V4 Conc Kind
# 1:  1   Bob 2001   38    b
# 2:  1   Bob 2002   22   NA
# 3:  1   Bob 2003   24    c
# 4:  2   Ana 2001   77    b
# 5:  2   Ana 2002   31    c
# 6:  2   Ana 2003   29    b
# 7:  3 Smith 2001   91    c
# 8:  3 Smith 2002    2    c
# 9:  3 Smith 2003   49   NA
#10:  4   Sam 2001   21   NA
#11:  4   Sam 2002   30    a
#12:  4   Sam 2003    9    b
#13:  5   Big 2001   62    a
#14:  5   Big 2002   66    a
#15:  5   Big 2003   38    c
#16: NA  Lulu 2001   12   NA
#17: NA  Lulu 2002   26    a
#18: NA  Lulu 2003   30   NA
```

Edit for many id columns:

```
idvars = grep("_", names(DT), invert = TRUE)
dcast(melt(DT, id.vars = idvars)
        [, `:=`(var      = sub('_.*', '', variable),
                year     = sub('.*_', '', variable),
                variable = NULL)],
      ... ~ var, value.var='value')
```

Comment: but in my real problem I have not only "ID" and "Name" but many more, all that don't end with _year

Comment: I'll try. Though I'm sad to see data.table can't offer a simple solution (such as reshape). This solution seems quite convoluted. In the meanwhile could you explain the meaning of  ...  and `:=`  ,  please?

Comment: @skan see `?dcast` and `?":="` respectively

Comment: As far as I've tried your solution is the only one that works even with missing or unordered years.   Though it would be great to see something simpler.

Comment: There is a little problem, some names contain "_" but are not of the form  "_xxxx" where xxxx is the year. I think we need to use grep("_([0-9]{4})$",names(my) , invert = TRUE) instead

Comment: I've tried your solution with my database and I get the error:

"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 756.5 Mb" even though I have 16GB of RAM (and 65GB of pagefile).
Any trick?  
Any automatic way of doing it by parts?

Comment: @skan I'd start with first figuring out which operation gives that error. Is it the `melt`, the assignment or the `dcast`

Comment: yes it's the melt.  I think I'm going to split (by rows) the csv file in severa parts and later join them again.

Comment: @skan ok; if you can replicate the issue with a reproducible example, you might want to also post it on the `data.table` github page - in case it's a bug

Comment: And melt(DT, id.vars = idvars) works for a small data.table such as the example,   but  melt(DT, id.vars = idvars)[, `:=`(var      = sub('_.*', '', variable),
              year     = sub('.*_', '', variable),
              variable = NULL)]  doesn't produce any output.  Why?
It only works if included inside a dcast

Comment: @skan `:=` returns invisibly (see `?invisible`). Add extra empty `[]` at the end.

Comment: There is a problem when the name contains additional underscores.  For example first_Kind_2002.  I had to modify the var expression with var = sub('_([0-9]{4})$', '', variable)

Comment: But I don't know how to modify the sub within the year.  Fortunatelly the last sub seems to output the last part of the string.  How would you write the sub to remove first and get Kind_2002?

Comment: I've found another problem with this approach.  If some columns are numeric and some are text it converts all the columns to text.

Comment: @skan yeah, that's a tough one to address since the above `melt` will throw everything together and choose the type that would accommodate all the data (it also warns about this appropriately). You could use `type.convert` after you're done.

Comment: I've being parsing every step and found that the melt step could be a big problem when working with large datatables. If you have a data.table with just 100000 rows x 1000 columns and use half of the columns as id.vars the output is 50000000 x 500, just too much to continue.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve this on scale using `reshape()` from `base` R, without having to explicitly name variables.

```
# First we get indices of colnames that have format "_1234" at the end 
tomelt <- grep("_([0-9]{4})$",names(DT))

# Now we use these indices to reshape data
reshape(DT, varying = tomelt, sep = "_", 
        direction = 'long', idvar = "ID", timevar = "Year)
#    ID  Name Year Kind Conc
# 1:  1   Bob 2001    b   38
# 2:  2   Ana 2001    b   77
# 3:  3 Smith 2001    c   91
# 4:  4   Sam 2001   NA   21
# 5:  5   Big 2001    a   62
# 6: NA  Lulu 2001   NA   12
...
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it with data.table?  I would like to learn to, and my database is really big.  I've added a solution on my question but it doesn't populate properly the year column.

Answer (score 2):

If we are looking for `data.table` solution, extract the prefix part from the `names` of the "DT" and use the `unique` elements as `patterns` in the `measure` argument in `melt`.  Similarly, the suffix from "Year" is extracted and replace the numeric index with that.

```
nm <- unique(sub("_\\d+", "", names(DT)[-(1:2)]))
yr <- unique(sub("\\D+_", "", names(DT)[-(1:2)]))
melt(DT, measure = patterns(paste0("^", nm)), value.name = nm, 
                   variable.name = "Year")[, Year := yr[Year]][]
#    ID  Name Year Kind Conc
# 1:  1   Bob 2001    b   38
# 2:  2   Ana 2001    b   77
# 3:  3 Smith 2001    c   91
# 4:  4   Sam 2001   NA   21
# 5:  5   Big 2001    a   62
# 6: NA  Lulu 2001   NA   12
# 7:  1   Bob 2002   NA   22
# 8:  2   Ana 2002    c   31
# 9:  3 Smith 2002    c    2
#10:  4   Sam 2002    a   30
#11:  5   Big 2002    a   66
#12: NA  Lulu 2002    a   26
#13:  1   Bob 2003    c   24
#14:  2   Ana 2003    b   29
#15:  3 Smith 2003   NA   49
#16:  4   Sam 2003    b    9
#17:  5   Big 2003    c   38
#18: NA  Lulu 2003   NA   30
```

Comment: both this and the other answer rely on column order being identical between the various values (that fact is more obvious in this one)

Comment: @eddi Yes, that is right, but in the OP's post there is no indication that it is not in order

Comment: It's true, a generic option would be better. It's strange to see the solution with base R reshape is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is interested I post here my full solution,
able to work with datasets bigger than memory. It uses some of your ideas and some mine.
My data is the file file.csv (or you can even do it with a compressed file using fread("unzip -c name.zip").

```
## Initialization
nline <- 1500000  # total number of lines  or use wc -l to do it automatically.
chunk <- 5000    # change it according to your memory and number of columns.
times <- ceiling(nline/chunk)
name <- names(fread("file.csv", stringsAsFactors=F, integer64 = "character", nrows=0, na.strings=c("", "NA")) )
idvars =  grep("_20[0-9][0-9]$",name , invert = TRUE) 

# Now we loop every chunk

for(iter in 0:(times-1)) {
  my <- fread("file.csv", stringsAsFactors=F, integer64 = "character", skip=1+(iter*chunk), nrows=chunk, na.strings=c("", "NA")) 
  colnames(my) <- name
  temp <- melt(my, id.vars = idvars)  
    newfile <- dcast(
    temp[, `:=`(var = sub('_20[0-9][0-9]$', '', variable), year = sub('.*_', '', variable), variable = NULL)],  
    ... ~ var, value.var='value')  
  fwrite(newfile, "long.csv", quote=FALSE, sep=",", append=T)
  rm(temp); rm(newfile); rm(my); gc()
  }
```

#### #

As said before the problem with this method is that it converts all the value to character but if you save them to a file and read the file again (as here) you get the proper classes.

In case of very large files this method is very slow.

I encourage you to improve this solution or suggest any generic solution with tidyr, splitstackshape or other packages.

Or even better it would be great to do it with a database such as sqlite.

The solution should work on datasets with unordered columns or even with "_" in the middle of the name, such as:

```
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(   
  ID = c(1:15),
  Name = c("Bob","Ana","Smith","Sam","Big","Lulu", "Loli", "Chochi", "Tom", "Dick", "Pet", "Shin", "Rock", "Pep", "XXX"),
  Kind_2001 = factor(sample(c(letters[1:3], NA), 15, TRUE)),
  Kind_2002 = factor(sample(c(letters[1:3], NA), 15, TRUE)),
  Kind_2003 = factor(sample(c(letters[1:3], NA), 15, TRUE)),
  Conc_2004 = sample(49,15),
  aa_Conc_2001 = c(sample(99,14), NA),
  Conc_2002 = sample(79,15)
)
```